# Blocks Got Swapped in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I m using drupal 7 for my project. I created 2 blocks in lower region. 
Block name "Testimonials - home page" Another Block name "Video - home page".
The order was correct yesterday. But today Both blocks got swapped. It showing Video block first then Testimonial second.
Since i m new to drupal system, can you suggest to how fix the right order  permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because the two blocks have the same weight (position number). To check this go to admin/structure/blocks and click "Show row weights" at the top right. If they both have the same number in the drop-down, change one of them - the lower the number block will appear first.

Comment: Please note: if you set the weight of your block in php and not through the administrative interface, in order to update the weight you will need to write an update hook.